# Confused by the answer of this Riemann sum approximation question.

Tags: calculus, approximation

> $$\begin{array}{ | c | c | } \hline 
> n & \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{x_k}\right)\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \\ \hline 
> 100 & 5.19 \\ \hline 
> 200 & 5.88 \\ \hline 
> 300 & 6.28  \\ \hline 
> 400 & 6.47  \\ \hline 
> 500 & 6.79  \\ \hline 
> \hline \end{array}$$
>
> The table above shows several Riemann sum approximations to $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\, \mathrm{d}x$ using right-hand endpoints of $n$ subintervals of equal length of the interval $\left[0,1\right]$. Which of the following statements best describes the limit of the Riemann sums as $n$ approaches infinity?
>
> (A) the limit of the Riemann sums is a finite number less than 10
>
> (B) The limit of the Riemann sums is a finite number greater than 10
>
> (C) The limit of the Riemann sums does not exist because $\left(\frac{1}{x_n}\right)\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ does not approach $0$.
>
> (D) The limit of the Riemann sums does not exist because it is a sum of infinitely many positive number.
>
> (E) The limit of the Riemann sums does not exist because $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\, \mathrm{d}x$ does not exist.  **The correct answer**

---

*Now to my confusion*

First, I understand the correct answer just from reading the problem.  I know that if one takes a Riemann sum to infinity then it is the same as the Integral of the function.  My problem is that --> I don't understand how to change the Riemann sum to an integral.<--

I don't want to just be able to answer the question, but to literally suck all the possible knowledge possible out of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your sum is in the form: 
$$\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{x_k}\right)\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{x_k}\right)\left(\frac{k+1}{n}-\frac{k}{n}\right)$$
Interpret the RHS as Integral i.e. $$\int f(x) dx$$ with $$dx=\left(\frac{k+1}{n}-\frac{k}{n}\right);\;\;f(x)=\left(\frac{1}{x_k}\right)$$
The bounds of the interval will be the largest and smallest value of $$\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)$$ i.e. 0 and 1 in your case.

---

It's worthwhile to recall the interpretation of Riemann Sum:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}f{(t_i)}(x_{i+1}-x_i)$$ where $t_i$ is some intermediate value in the interval.

Comment: Please, explain why the sum is in that form.

Comment: That is the way to interpret the sum. You interpret $1/n$ as $dx$.

Comment: I am stuck on why you changed the $1/n$ to the difference of two fractions involving $k$?

Comment: See the edited answer.

Comment: awesome!  totally didn't see that before.  *did you forget the () around $t_i$?